# How to COUNTIF on a odd/even rows within a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I COUNTIF on a certain amount of odd or even rows within a column - I've tried tons of suggestions but none work correctly when done vertically.

This is the closest I got but it only seems to work and output when I select one cell - so not helpful.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(ISODD(ROWS($D301))*$D301=2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW` instead of `ROWS`

`ROW` will return an array of row numbers.  While `ROWS` will return a single number representing the number of rows in the reference:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISODD(ROW($D$301:$D$400)))*($D$301:$D$400=2))
```

Comment: It worked! One more quick question, If i wanted to reference the data from another sheet would it just be 

=SUMPRODUCT((ISODD(ROW(Sheetname!$D$301:$D$400)))*(Sheetname!$D$301:$D$400=2))?

It doesnt work for me

Comment: @John What error do you get?

Comment: It just tells me there's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type in a formula? etc etc. I am also seeing a #Ref! in the actual cell

Comment: #ref means you misspelled the sheet name.  I put your formula in my excel with a sheet named `Sheetname` and it worked.  Does the sheet name you are using have a space in it?

Comment: It does not. Its just all capitals with the bridging of the two words with an & sign, no space. I even copy pasted it from the sheet itself so i'm unsure? Ex: HELLO&HI EDIT: It works if I have a basic name for a sheet, ex: sheet2

Comment: Try: `=SUMPRODUCT((ISODD(ROW('HELLO&HI'!$D$301:$D$400)))*('HELLO&HI'!$D$301:$D$400=2))` with `''` around the sheet name.

Comment: Awesome! That worked! thank you so much - I never would have even thought of that

Comment: @John ensure to accept the answer by ticking the check mark beside the answer. So it helps someone in future looking for a solution like your and the comments related with your post would help to understand more clearly